# How to prevent the map from moving when creating Google Maps markers?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps-markers

I have successfully displayed the markers and set them to open the infoWindow by default. However, I encountered another issue: whenever the current map view is not within the display range of these markers, the map automatically moves to show the markers. When updating the locations of these markers, I want to prevent the map from moving automatically. I just want the markers to be generated silently.

```js
          for (const location of this.transformedData) {
            
            const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng),
              map: this.map,
              title: location.addr,
              icon: { url: location.url, scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50) },
              center: this.center
            });

            const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: location.infoWindowContent
            });

            infowindow.open(this.map, marker);

            this.markers.push(marker);
          }
```

I tried resetting the map center at the end of the loop, but it didn't work.

```
this.currentMapCenter = this.map.getCenter();
.
.
.
//end of the loop
if (this.currentMapCenter) {
          this.map.setCenter(this.currentMapCenter);
        }
```